# Are interfaces redundant if using abstracts as an interface?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, interface, domain-driven-design, abstract-class

I'm reading through Design Patterns by GoF and I'm starting to wonder.  Are interfaces redundant if you're using an abstract *as* the interface in languages like C#?  Let's put multiple inheritance aside for a moment, as I understand you can only achieve that (in C#) through interfaces.

I'm trying to apply this logic to DDD in C#.  Almost every example and implementation I've ever seen uses interfaces.  I'm starting to wonder why.  Could the abstract class be used instead?  It seems to me that this would be a more robust solution, but then again I could be missing something, which is why I'm asking here.

**Summary:**

- **Question 1:** In the context of OOP with a language that only supports single inheritance, if designed properly what are some uses
  of interfaces **over** the abstract class?
- **Question 2:** In the context of DDD, if designed properly what are the uses of interfaces **over** the abstract class?

**Note:**
I've read through all the similar questions listed, but none seem to give me an answer.  If I missed one, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For question 1: regardless of support for multiple inheritance interfaces are contract specifications, abstract classes are base classes.

Interfaces provide a way for a class to specify a set of capabilities ( think IDisposable, IEnumerable, etc ) and it's recommended that they obey the [Interface Segregation Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).

Abstract classes should implement a concept that can be extended, or that can have different implementations depending on the context ( think [HttpContextBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase.aspx), AbstractButton etc ).

The biggest difference between interfaces and abstract classes is conceptual. You can argue that, except inheritance, an interface is the same as an abstract class with only abstract methods, but conceptually they represent different things.

As for question 2: in the context of DDD interfaces are implementations details. I dare say you can do DDD and not use interfaces or abstract classes, or even inheritance. As long as you have your bounded contexts, aggregates, entities and VOs well defined.

In conclusion, when you try to express a contract use an interface, when you want to indicate that your class has some capability, implement an interface. When you have a concept for which you can provide more implementations depending on context, use a base class ( abstract or not ).

When you think about it like this, the decision of the language makers ( c# ) to allow only single inheritance, but allow implementation of multiple interfaces makes a lot of sense.

Comment: The reference to ISP really helped here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of Interfaces is precisely that there is no multiple-inheritance.  By using an Interface you can allow classes like Forms, UserControls, Components, etc to participate in interactions that would otherwise be diffucult/impossible.

I recommend doing both.  I usually create an interface, and (if possible) then create an abstract class that inherits that interface to provde any common or default implementaion of that interface.  This gives you the best of both worlds.

Comment: How do you figure there's no multiple-inheritance?  C# can only achieve multiple-inheritance through interfaces.  I currently do both, an interface and an abstract.  If I switched it all to the abstract though, nothing would really change.  Of course I would have to change the declarations to the abstract from the interface, but otherwise no algorithm would change.  What's the advantage to the interface?

Comment: While the syntax is similar, it is better to state that you can ***implement*** multiple interfaces, but you can ***inherit*** only one class.

Comment: I have a small framework I use that has an interface called ILogicController.  This interface has methods that work as part of a state machine.  If I were to convert that to a class called AbstarctLogicControlBase, then my WinForms and UserControls can no longer participate in that framework.  A form, say LoginForm, inherits from System.Windows.Forms.Form already.  it cannot also inherit from AbstarctLogicControlBase.

Answer (score 1):

interfaces are not redundant. an interface is independent of implementation while abstract classes are implementation. code that uses an interface does not have to be changed or recompiled if some implementation class changes.

the advantage is above. if you are doing ddd, start out with concrete classes and write some tests. refactor common stuff into base classes (some will be abstract). if there is a reason to make an interface go ahead and do so. repeat until done.

Comment: I get what you're saying here, but it doesn't answer either question.  If I change my interface then all classes would need to be modified the same as if I changed the abstract class.  The two seem to do the same thing in that case.  Set aside that abstracts can be full or partial implementations, if you're using it as an interface, instead of an interface type, what's the advantage?